# Simplest way to download and unzip files in Node.js cross-platform?

Tags: node.js, zip

Just looking for a simple solution to downloading and unzipping `.zip` or `.tar.gz` files in Node.js on any operating system.

Not sure if this is built in or I have to use a separate library.  Any ideas?  Looking for just a couple lines of code so when the next zip file comes that I want to download in node, it's a no brainer.  Feel like this should be easy and/or built in, but I can't find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Node has builtin support for gzip and deflate via the [zlib module](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html):

```
var zlib = require('zlib');

zlib.gunzip(gzipBuffer, function(err, result) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);

    console.log(result);
});
```

**Edit:** You can even `pipe` the data directly through e.g. `Gunzip` (using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request)):

```
var request = require('request'),
    zlib = require('zlib'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    out = fs.createWriteStream('out');

// Fetch http://example.com/foo.gz, gunzip it and store the results in 'out'
request('http://example.com/foo.gz').pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(out);
```

For tar archives, there is Isaacs' [tar module](https://github.com/isaacs/node-tar), which is used by npm.

**Edit 2:** Updated answer as `zlib` doesn't support the `zip` format. This will only work for `gzip`.

Comment: No. Neither of these examples work.

node.js's zlib module is only for streams and buffers that represent singular resources; not zip or tar archives.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the question.

He is not trying to uncompress single streams or a single file.

He is trying to extract the files from entire archives.

As you mention: Isaacs' tar module will indeed work with tars but your code for zips will not extract the files from zip archives.

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple files within the same archive.

Answer (score 153):

It's 2017 (October 26th, to be exact).

For an ancient and pervasive technology such as unzip I would expect there to exist a fairly popular, mature node.js unzip library that is "stagnant" and "unmaintained" because it is "complete".

However, most libraries appear either to be completely terrible or to have commits recently as just a few months ago. This is quite concerning... so I've gone through several unzip libraries, read their docs, and tried their examples to try to figure out WTF. For example, I've tried these:

- thejoshwolfe/[`yauzl`](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl)
- antelle/[`node-stream-zip`](https://github.com/antelle/node-stream-zip)
- ZJONSSON/[`node-unzipper`](https://github.com/ZJONSSON/node-unzipper)
- EvanOxfeld/[`node-unzip`](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip)
- Stuk/[`jszip`](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip)
- kriskowal/[`zip`](https://github.com/kriskowal/zip)

Update 2020: Haven't tried it yet, but there's also [archiver](https://www.archiverjs.com/)

### Top Recommendation: `yauzl`

Works great for completely downloaded file. Not as great for streaming.

Well documented. Works well. Makes sense.

### 2nd Pick: `node-stream-zip`

antelle's [`node-stream-zip`](https://github.com/antelle/node-stream-zip) seems to be the best

Install:

```
npm install --save node-stream-zip
```

Usage:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var StreamZip = require('node-stream-zip');

var zip = new StreamZip({
  file: './example.zip'
, storeEntries: true
});

zip.on('error', function (err) { console.error('[ERROR]', err); });

zip.on('ready', function () {
  console.log('All entries read: ' + zip.entriesCount);
  //console.log(zip.entries());
});

zip.on('entry', function (entry) {
  var pathname = path.resolve('./temp', entry.name);
  if (/\.\./.test(path.relative('./temp', pathname))) {
      console.warn("[zip warn]: ignoring maliciously crafted paths in zip file:", entry.name);
      return;
  }

  if ('/' === entry.name[entry.name.length - 1]) {
    console.log('[DIR]', entry.name);
    return;
  }

  console.log('[FILE]', entry.name);
  zip.stream(entry.name, function (err, stream) {
    if (err) { console.error('Error:', err.toString()); return; }

    stream.on('error', function (err) { console.log('[ERROR]', err); return; });

    // example: print contents to screen
    //stream.pipe(process.stdout);

    // example: save contents to file
    fs.mkdir(
      path.dirname(pathname),
      { recursive: true },
      function (err) {
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathname));
      }
    );
  });
});
```

**Security Warning**:

Not sure if this checks `entry.name` for maliciously crafted paths that would resolve incorrectly (such as `../../../foo` or `/etc/passwd`).

You can easily check this yourself by comparing `/\.\./.test(path.relative('./to/dir', path.resolve('./to/dir', entry.name)))`.

**Pros**: (Why do I think it's the best?)

- can unzip normal files (maybe not some crazy ones with weird extensions)
- can stream
- seems to not have to load the whole zip to read entries
- has examples in normal JavaScript (not compiled)
- doesn't include the kitchen sink (i.e. url loading, S3, or db layers)
- uses some existing code from a popular library
- doesn't have too much senseless hipster or ninja-foo in the code

**Cons**:

- Swallows errors like a hungry hippo
- Throws strings instead of errors (no stack traces)
- `zip.extract()` doesn't seem to work (hence I used `zip.stream()` in my example)

### Runner up: node-unzipper

Install:

```
npm install --save unzipper
```

Usage:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var unzipper = require('unzipper');

fs.createReadStream('./example.zip')
  .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
  .on('entry', function (entry) {
    var fileName = entry.path;
    var type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'

    console.log();
    if (/\/$/.test(fileName)) {
      console.log('[DIR]', fileName, type);
      return;
    }

    console.log('[FILE]', fileName, type);

    // TODO: probably also needs the security check

    entry.pipe(process.stdout/*fs.createWriteStream('output/path')*/);
    // NOTE: To ignore use entry.autodrain() instead of entry.pipe()
  });
```

**Pros**:

- Seems to work in a similar manner to `node-stream-zip`, but less control
- A more functional fork of `unzip`
- Seems to run in serial rather than in parallel

**Cons**:

- Kitchen sink much? Just includes a ton of stuff that's not related to unzipping
- Reads the whole file (by chunk, which is fine), not just random seeks

Comment: Is nobody else surprised that in 2019 there is no built-in function that allows you to extract a `.zip` into a given location?

Comment: I tried adm-zip and yauzl/yazl. yauzl/yazl supoort newer version of zip protocol and less buggy.

Comment: You might want to add that streaming a zip is technically an invalid use of a zip file. zip was made back in floppy disk days so there is an option to freshen/add new files to an existing zip. Let's say your zip had 3 files A,B,C. Instead of writing the entire zip pkzip just adds new A to the end of the file and then puts a new central directory at the end. So if you stream you'll get 2 A files one of them invalid.

Comment: mkdirp is undefined!

Comment: @Felipe Hooray! Almost 2021 and it is still painful to deal with zip files in node!

Comment: @RicardoGSaraiva Now it's `fs.mkdir(x, { recursive: true })`.

Comment: Re the comment about archiver, as of Jan 2021 it's still pack only (it does not unzip/unpack)

Comment: unzip cannot work on nodejs v12+, so please use unzipper instead

Comment: I highly recommend node-stream-zip with very straight forward usage in their new updated document: https://github.com/antelle/node-stream-zip when trying to extracting files (I have only tested this on Linux)

Comment: to avoid: "[ERROR] ReferenceError: path is not defined", just add this to the head: "const path = require('path');"

Comment: @JuliodeLeon It's 2023, it's still a mess. I just want to unzip a file, without memory leaks and keep the Linux file permissions.

Comment: "unzipit" package is the one I had the most success after comparing a few dozen alternatives.

Comment: yauzl seems to be abandoned as well. 4 years without updates and now it's also throwing a deprecation warning for the Buffer() constructor due to one of the dependencies becoming outdated.

Answer (score 47):

Checkout [adm-zip](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip).

ADM-ZIP is a pure JavaScript implementation for zip data compression for NodeJS.

> The library allows you to:
>
> - decompress zip files directly to disk or in-memory buffers
> - compress files and store them to disk in `.zip` format or in compressed buffers
> - update content of/add new/delete files from an existing `.zip`

Comment: I was having errors with any zlib implementation that would kick out a n "Invalid Block Type" (error code is "Z_DATA_ERROR") error, but windows unzip would work fine on the file. adm-zip also appears to work just fine.

Comment: "Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found" with cygwin zipped file. Bloargh.

Comment: Can we `unzip` file at server side also with this module?

Comment: I get this error using the adm-zip package, that's unworkable for me - https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/issues/25

Comment: how come nobody experienced any problems with the way it extracts the zip to target path?

Comment: It cannot unzip large file. E.g, trying to unzip my file with a size `2857964996` throw `RangeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "2857964996" is invalid for option "size"`

Comment: I have had very bad experience using adm-zip for large files. When I try to unzip a large file on a disk space that is too small, adm-zip throws "Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found" instead of ENOSPC. 

When I try to create a zip file where there is not enough space, adm-zip fails silently instead of throwing ENOSPC.

Answer (score 26):

I tried a few of the nodejs unzip libraries including adm-zip and unzip, then settled on extract-zip which is a wrapper around yauzl. Seemed the simplest to implement.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-zip

```
var extract = require('extract-zip')
extract(zipfile, { dir: outputPath }, function (err) {
   // handle err
})
```

Comment: +1 [extract-zip](https://github.com/maxogden/extract-zip) and [yauzl](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl) seem to be maintained more frequently than others. No commits to [unzip](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip) and [adm-zip](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip) in 3 years and tons of issues at the time of writing!

Comment: Side-note: You can also use it as promise, no need for promisifying.

Answer (score 17):

[yauzl](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl) is a robust library for unzipping. Design principles:

- Follow the spec. Don't scan for local file headers. Read the central directory for file metadata.
- Don't block the JavaScript thread. Use and provide async APIs.
- Keep memory usage under control. Don't attempt to buffer entire files in RAM at once.
- Never crash (if used properly). Don't let malformed zip files bring down client applications who are trying to catch errors.
- Catch unsafe filenames entries. A zip file entry throws an error if its file name starts with "/" or /[A-Za-z]:// or if it contains ".." path segments or "\" (per the spec).

Currently has 97% test coverage.

Comment: has been packaged with an even simpler interface https://github.com/maxogden/extract-zip

Comment: https://github.com/kevva/decompress also leverages yauzl

Answer (score 5):

I found success with the following, works with .zip
(Simplified here for posting: no error checking & just unzips all files to current folder)

```
function DownloadAndUnzip(URL){
    var unzip = require('unzip');
    var http = require('http');
    var request = http.get(URL, function(response) {
        response.pipe(unzip.Extract({path:'./'}))
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was looking forward this for a long time, and found no simple working example, but based on these answers I created the `downloadAndUnzip()` function.

The usage is quite simple:

```
downloadAndUnzip('http://your-domain.com/archive.zip', 'yourfile.xml')
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data); // unzipped content of yourfile.xml in root of archive.zip
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

And here is the declaration:

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
var request = require('request');

var downloadAndUnzip = function (url, fileName) {

    /**
     * Download a file
     * 
     * @param url
     */
    var download = function (url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            request({
                url: url,
                method: 'GET',
                encoding: null
            }, function (err, response, body) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(body);
            });
        });
    };

    /**
     * Unzip a Buffer
     * 
     * @param buffer
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    var unzip = function (buffer) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            var resolved = false;

            var zip = new AdmZip(buffer);
            var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); // an array of ZipEntry records

            zipEntries.forEach(function (zipEntry) {
                if (zipEntry.entryName == fileName) {
                    resolved = true;
                    resolve(zipEntry.getData().toString('utf8'));
                }
            });

            if (!resolved) {
                reject(new Error('No file found in archive: ' + fileName));
            }
        });
    };


    return download(url)
        .then(unzip);
};
```

Comment: this is not scalable, as it uses memory

Comment: Code might be much simplier:
    const zipEntries = new AdmZip(buffer).getEntries()
    const output = zipEntries.filter(zipEntry => zipEntry.entryName == 
    fileName).map(zipEntry => zipEntry.getData().toString('utf8'))
    return output.length > 0 ? resolve(output) : reject(new Error('No file found in 
    archive: ' + fileName))

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [gunzip-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gunzip-file)

```
import gunzip from 'gunzip-file';

const unzipAll = async () => {
  try {
    const compFiles = fs.readdirSync('tmp')
    await Promise.all(compFiles.map( async file => {
      if(file.endsWith(".gz")){
        gunzip(`tmp/${file}`, `tmp/${file.slice(0, -3)}`)
      }
    }));
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and extract for `.tar.gz`:

```
const https = require("https");
const tar = require("tar");

https.get("https://url.to/your.tar.gz", function(response) {
  response.pipe(
    tar.x({
      strip: 1,
      C: "some-dir"
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having issues with the integrity of the extracted files and the only solution the worked for me was to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/decompress

Answer (score -1):

Another working example:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var tar = require('tar');
var ftp = require('ftp');

var files = [];

var conn = new ftp();
conn.on('connect', function(e) 
{
    conn.auth(function(e) 
    {
        if (e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        conn.get('/tz/tzdata-latest.tar.gz', function(e, stream) 
        {
            stream.on('success', function() 
            {
                conn.end();

                console.log("Processing files ...");

                for (var name in files)
                {
                    var file = files[name];

                    console.log("filename: " + name);
                    console.log(file);
                }
                console.log("OK")
            });
            stream.on('error', function(e) 
            {
                console.log('ERROR during get(): ' + e);
                conn.end();
            });

            console.log("Reading ...");

            stream
            .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
            .pipe(tar.Parse())
            .on("entry", function (e) 
            {    
                var filename = e.props["path"];
                console.log("filename:" + filename);
                if( files[filename] == null )
                {
                    files[filename] = "";
                }
                e.on("data", function (c) 
                {
                    files[filename] += c.toString();
                })    
            });
        });
    });
})
.connect(21, "ftp.iana.org");
```

Comment: gzip is not the same as .zip

Comment: note that tar now has tar.Extract([options]) with the option path: '/path' that saves the lower half of the script, see https://www.npmjs.org/package/tar

Answer (score -2):

If you don't need to put multiple files into archive, but rather compress one file or just a string contents, then `zlib.deflateRaw`/`zlib.inflateRaw` can be used.

Here is an example how to compress in-memory string on macOS/iOS and decompress it in NodeJS.

```swift
// Swift, macOS/iOS
let data = "HelloZip!".data(using: .utf8)!
let compressedData = (data as NSData).compressed(using: .zlib) as Data
let compressedDataAsBase64EncodedString = compressedData.base64EncodedString()
print(compressedDataAsBase64EncodedString)
// Prints: 80jNycmPyixQBAA=
```

```js
// JS, AWS Lambda.
import zlib from "zlib";

const compressedDataAsBase64EncodedString = "80jNycmPyixQBAA="
const compressedData = Buffer.from(compressedDataAsBase64EncodedString, "base64")
const data = zlib.inflateRawSync(compressedData)
console.log(data.toString())
// Prints: HelloZip!
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked which is about *unzipping*.

Answer (score -3):

You can simply extract the existing zip files also by using "unzip". It will work for any size files and you need to add it as a dependency from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip).

```js
fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(unzip.Extract({path:moveIntoFolder})).on('close', function(){
        //To do after unzip
    callback();
  });
```

Comment: Please explain what `unzip` is and if it's a built in package or requires you to npm install it.

Comment: [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip) is the link for the unzip package. It is not a built-in package.