# How can I uncompress a gzip file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, zip, gzip, zip.js

I have gotten an  `ArrayBuffer` data (called s as follows which consist of many blocks) from our serve side,the blob is generated as follows:

```
var blob=new Blob([s.slice(4,82838)]);
```

but the blob I have made is a gzip data;How can I uncompress it in javascript?
I have tried `zip.js` but it didn't work?(and I still puzzled why it doesn't work).
please tell me a method to un-compress the blob,thank you. (my English is poor,sorry)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching zipped text file and unzipping in client browers, feasible in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727856/fetching-zipped-text-file-and-unzipping-in-client-browers-feasible-in-javascrip) (The accepted answer provides a link that should be of interest to you.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the browser I have used [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako)

You may do something like..

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
    var result = pako.inflate(event.target.result, { to: 'string' });
    console.log(result);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file));
```

If your environment is nodejs you have [zlib capabilities](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib)

Comment: but it always pull the error:pako.js:787 Uncaught incorrect header checkinflate @ pako.js:787reader.onload ? Do you know the matter?

Comment: Glad to hear this :) can you please mark the answer as resolved?

Comment: I‘d like to,but I don't know what to do?是不是在下面打个绿色的√(mark a green√ under the vote,is it？)

Answer (score 0):

In Nodejs, you can install unzip package.

```
npm install unzip
```

This is the [document](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip)