# Download gz file using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to download a gz file using ajax but didn't work.

Here What I get:

```
x1H4sIAAAAAAAAC82dzW8bORLF7/orGsjBNuAATRaL/THIwZMou8Y6diDLi52T7djajbDxB2xlFvPfL4u0I42cKP0uTwMEOcxI8c9sVr1ikY/9avSqmh78ejSuTqeTs7fTs8m4en8y6avLq8X89...
```

AJAX:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: base_url+'backups/create',
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching zipped text file and unzipping in client browsers, feasible in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727856/fetching-zipped-text-file-and-unzipping-in-client-browsers-feasible-in-javascri)

Comment: you can't download any kind of file using AJAX - it always ends up as a variable inside your JavaScript, instead of on the user's disk. You need to rethink your approach.