# How do I make use of an xml file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

In my server.js file, I make an HTTP GET request that is suppose to return xml. When I log the GET request's response to the console, it is gibberish containing lots of question marks and black diamonds as you can see in the photo below:[image]

When I take the same url that I'm using in my GET request and I open it in the browser it automatically downloads a gzip file, which after it's unzipped contains a legible xml file with the data (inside my text editor).

How do I get the xml in its correct form inside my server.js file? I need to make use of it in my program, not inside a text editor (obviously).

Here is my GET request:

```
axios.get('http://www2.jobs2careers.com/feed.php?id=1237-2595&c=1&pass=HeahE0W1ecAkkF0l')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

I've tried to extract the gzip file using the targz library as shown below:

```
axios.get('http://www2.jobs2careers.com/feed.php?id=1237-2595&c=1&pass=HeahE0W1ecAkkF0l')
  .then(function(response) {
    targz().extract(response.data, '/data', function(err){
      if (err) {
        console.log('Something is wrong ', err.stack);
      }
      console.log('Job done!');
    });
  });
```

I get an error in the console saying : "Path must be a string without null bytes". Should I be using the extract method from targz or am I just using it incorrectly? I'm trying to "extract" or unzip the response.data.

Comment: The answer is in your question: the response isn't an XML file, it's a gzip file. You need a node module that can extract it. Here's one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar.gz

Comment: You have also zlib https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_zlib_gzip

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148948/how-do-i-ungzip-decompress-a-nodejs-requests-module-gzip-response-body

Comment: I tried using the targz node module, but I don't think I'm using it correctly. I updated the question with my latest code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this: [Simplest way to download and unzip files in Node.js cross-platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308110/simplest-way-to-download-and-unzip-files-in-node-js-cross-platform)

```
var feedURL = 'http://www2.jobs2careers.com/feed.php?id=1237-2595&c=1&pass=HeahE0W1ecAkkF0l';

var request = require('request'),
    zlib = require('zlib'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    out = fs.createWriteStream('./feed.xml');

request(feedURL).pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the updated code, it appears you that the first parameter (response.data) needs to be set to a path on the filesystem of a gzip file, hence the null byte error. I would consider writing to the file system, then extract, or another module that would let you extract from a url.

When you do get the XML out of the extracted gzip file (which you are on the right path, no pun intended), you can use a node module such as [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js), which will parse the xml into a Javascript object, and makes it quite easy to work with.

Comment: So I figured out how to unzip the file and now it is saved in my root directory as feed.xml. I want to use xml2js to turn that xml into JSON. In the docs for xml2js, they give this example: 
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
The variable xml is set to a string. How do I set xml to the value of my file called feed.xml?

Comment: I'm assuming you have the feed.xml file saved locally at this point. From here you can use the [fs.readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_option) to set as your xml variable, then begin with parsing it as a string.

Comment: If do decide to go with readFileSync() or readFile(), don't forget to specify the encoding (most likely utf8) as the second parameter, otherwise you'll get a buffer.

Comment: When I tried readFile, I did specify encoding UTF8 but I still got a buffer anyway. I opened another question about that and no one could answer it either. It even got downvoted... haha

Comment: Shouldn't be the case, I've done this before with no issues. Do you have implementation code?

Comment: Actually I have it here: https://gist.github.com/MarcusHurney/bcbacbcc978985317c938c33afabfa83