# Extract zip into folder node via express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, zip

I try to find example where I can send a zip (like via postman) 
and get this zip in my handler and **unzip** **it so specified folder**
I didn't find much examples for zipping using `express` 
I want to unzip it in path `web/app`

I try something like the following which doesn't works for me , the zip file is not unzipped in the specified folder, any idea what im doing wrong ?

https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var fs = require('fs');
const dir = path.join(__dirname, 'web/app/');

if (req.file.mimetype === 'application/zip') {

    var unzip = zlib.createUnzip();

    var read = fs.createReadStream(req.file);
    var write = fs.createWriteStream(dir);
    //Transform stream which is unzipping the zipped file
    read.pipe(unzip).pipe(write);   
    console.log("unZipped Successfully");

}
```

Any working example will be very helpful, or reference where can I've problem...

while debug I see the that this is when the code failed

`var read = fs.createReadStream(req.file);`

any idea why?

I've also tried with

`var read = fs.createReadStream(req.file.body);`

the issue that I dont see the error, reason etc.

when I change it to

`var read = fs.createReadStream(req.file.buffer);`

the program doesnt exit and i was able to run it until the logger `console.log("unZipped Successfully");` but nothing happen...

if there any example with https://www.npmjs.com/package/yauzl **yauzl and multer**
 in my context it will be great

update- this is the postman request

[image]

Comment: Recieving files is always a bit of work. Maybe you could try to save the file and opening it with a gui for debugging purpose? You might get valueble info. One step at the time

Comment: This is easy using OS scripts. You didn't specify any restrictions about it, is there any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, `zlib` does not support extracting `zip` files.

I recommend [`formidable`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/) for handling files because

1. its battle tested
2. most widely used
3. avoids writing boilerplate plate code like reading filestream from request, storing and handling errors
4. easily configurable

**Prerequisites**
Install dependencies using `npm i -S extract-zip formidable express` or `yarn add extract-zip formidable express`

Bare minimal solution for your problem with `formidable` and `extract-zip`

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const extract = require('extract-zip')
const formidable = require('formidable');
const path = require('path');
const uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/');
const extractDir = path.join(__dirname, '/app/');
if (!fs.existsSync(uploadDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(uploadDir);
}
if (!fs.existsSync(extractDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(extractDir);
}

const server = express();

const uploadMedia = (req, res, next) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  // file size limit 100MB. change according to your needs
  form.maxFileSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.multiples = true;
  form.uploadDir = uploadDir;

  // collect all form files and fileds and pass to its callback
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    // when form parsing fails throw error
    if (err) return res.status(500).json({ error: err });

    if (Object.keys(files).length === 0) return res.status(400).json({ message: "no files uploaded" });
    
    // Iterate all uploaded files and get their path, extension, final extraction path
    const filesInfo = Object.keys(files).map((key) => {
      const file = files[key];
      const filePath = file.path;
      const fileExt = path.extname(file.name);
      const fileName = path.basename(file.name, fileExt);
      const destDir = path.join(extractDir, fileName);

      return { filePath, fileExt, destDir };
    });

    // Check whether uploaded files are zip files
    const validFiles = filesInfo.every(({ fileExt }) => fileExt === '.zip');

    // if uploaded files are not zip files, return error
    if (!validFiles) return res.status(400).json({ message: "unsupported file type" });

    res.status(200).json({ uploaded: true });

    // iterate through each file path and extract them
    filesInfo.forEach(({filePath, destDir}) => {
      // create directory with timestamp to prevent overwrite same directory names
      extract(filePath, { dir: `${destDir}_${new Date().getTime()}` }, (err) => {
        if (err) console.error('extraction failed.');
      });
    });
  });

  // runs when new file detected in upload stream
  form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
    // get the file base name `index.css.zip` => `index.html`
    const fileName = path.basename(file.name, path.extname(file.name));
    const fileExt = path.extname(file.name);
    // create files with timestamp to prevent overwrite same file names
    file.path = path.join(uploadDir, `${fileName}_${new Date().getTime()}${fileExt}`);
  });
}

server.post('/upload', uploadMedia);

server.listen(3000, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

This solution works for single/multiple file uploads. The one problem with this solution is, wrong file types will get uploaded to `uploaded` directory though server throw error.

**To test with postman:**
[image: postman image]

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue resloved!

Comment: Great Answer, helped me on this date!

Answer (score 2):

Without a full example it's tough to say what the real problem is. But according to [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) it says:

> In Express 4, req.files is no longer available on the req object by
>   default. To access uploaded files on the req.files object, use
>   multipart-handling middleware like busboy, multer, formidable,
>   multiparty, connect-multiparty, or pez.

So if you are not using a middleware library to handle uploading files, it's tough to tell what the value of `req.file` is.

I am also a bit worried that you are trying to use `zlib` to decompress a zip file, since the [library](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_zlib_unzip) only supports gzip.

> The zlib module provides compression functionality implemented using
>   Gzip and Deflate/Inflate

You would want to check for `req.file.mimetype === 'application/gzip'`

Here are some posts related to unzipping zip files:

- [How to download and unzip a zip file in memory in NodeJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359485/how-to-download-and-unzip-a-zip-file-in-memory-in-nodejs?rq=1)
- [Simplest way to download and unzip files in Node.js cross-platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308110/simplest-way-to-download-and-unzip-files-in-node-js-cross-platform)

Comment: `req.file.mimetype` works Based on File.extensions but not based on file type

Answer (score 2):

**Prerequisites**:

1. `npm i express unzipper multiparty bluebird`
2. Create `app/web` directory in your project root (or you can automate creation if you want).
3. Place all of these files into one directory.
4. Node version that supports `async/await` (7.6+ as far as I know)

**server.js**:

```
const express = require('express');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = require('fs');
const writeFile = Promise.promisify(fs.writeFile);

const { parseRequest, getFile } = require('./multipart');
const { extractFiles } = require('./zip')

const EXTRACT_DIR = 'web/app';

const app = express();

const uploadFile = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const body = await parseRequest(req);
    const bodyFile = getFile(body, 'file');
    if (!/\.zip$/.test(bodyFile.originalFilename)) {
      res.status(200).json({ notice: 'not a zip archive, skipping' })
      return;
    }
    const archiveFiles = await extractFiles(bodyFile);

    await Promise.each(archiveFiles, async (file) => {
      await writeFile(EXTRACT_DIR + '/' + file.path, file.buffer);
    })
    res.status(200).end();
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).end();
  }
};

app.post('/files', uploadFile);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App is listening on port 3000');
});
```

**multipart.js**

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const { Form } = require('multiparty');

function parseRequest (req, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const form = new Form(options)
        form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve({ fields, files });
        });
    });
}

function getFile (body, field) {
    const bodyFile = body.files[field];
    const value = bodyFile ? bodyFile[0] : null;
    return value || null;
}

module.exports = {
    parseRequest,
    getFile,
};
```

**zip.js**

```
const unzip = require('unzipper');
const fs = require('fs');

async function extractFiles (file) {
    const files = [];
    await fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(unzip.Parse()).on('entry', async entry => {
    // Cleanup system hidden files (or drop this code if not needed)
        if (
            entry.type !== 'File'
            || /^__MACOSX/.test(entry.path)
            || /.DS_Store/.test(entry.path)
        ) {
            entry.autodrain()
            return
        }
        const pathArr = entry.path.split('/');
        const path = entry.path;
        const buffer = await entry.buffer();
        files.push({ buffer, path, originalFilename: pathArr[pathArr.length - 1] });
    }).promise();
    return files;
}

module.exports = {
    extractFiles,
};
```

**Usage**:

1. Start a server with `node server`
2. Send your file in `file` field in request (key `file` in postman). Example in curl `curl -XPOST -F 'file=@../ttrra-dsp-agency-api/banner.zip' 'localhost:3000/files'`)

**Downsides**:

1. Unzipped files are stored in buffer so this method doesn't work great and *is not recommended for big archives*.

Comment: Thanks, I want to check it but I cannot use `unzipper` since its not supporting large file, only `yauzl` and the wrapper on top `extract-zip` , thanks

Comment: in addition it will be great if you can add the code which  create the app folder if doesnt exist

Answer (score -1):

This is my code for uploading a file to **express server**.

```
//require express library
var express = require('express');
//require the express router
var router = express.Router();
//require multer for the file uploads
var multer = require('multer');

//File Upload

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  // destino del fichero
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/logo')
  },
  // renombrar fichero
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post("/", upload.array("uploads[]", 1), function (req, res) {
  res.json('Uploaded logo successfully');
});


module.exports = router;
```