# ReactJS and SupaBase - unzip an uploaded file and store in DB

Tags: reactjs, supabase

What would be the most efficient way to handle unzipping of a file and storing then uploading the unzipped file to Supabase?
There is no server-side available for SupaBase, so should I host an API elswhere that takes care of the unzipping part and eventually uploads the extracted file to SupaBase?

Answer (score 1):

### Small Files (Supabase Only Solution)

For small files, you can create an Edge Function that uses a [decompression stream](https://medium.com/deno-the-complete-reference/zip-and-unzip-files-in-deno-ee282da7369f):

```
const src = await Deno.open("./testdata/singleFile.txt.gz");
const dest = await Deno.open("./testdata/singleFile.txt", {
  create: true,
  write: true,
});
src.readable
  .pipeThrough(new DecompressionStream("gzip"))
  .pipeTo(dest.writable);
```

Then you can use this stream to pass the object to Supabase by tweaking this [upload to storage](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/blob/master/examples/edge-functions/supabase/functions/file-upload-storage/index.ts) example to take this decompression stream.

### Large Files:

For large files, then it would probably be a better idea to create a [server to extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244720/extract-zip-into-folder-node-via-express) and then upload it to Supabase Storage after the extraction was completed.