# No such file or directory when i want read data from extracted files

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, unzip

I have a zip folder that contain a html file.
I want to extract the zip in a directory then read the content of the html.
In this code i can extract the zip folder but when i want  read the content of the extracted file i found this error 'No such file or directory...' eve the file exist in the write path but i think that my code read the content of the html before the extraction.How can i fix this please.

```
var unzip = require('unzip');
 var stream =  fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: outputPath }));
stream.on('finish',function({console.log('done')});
 console.log(fs.readFileSync('outputPath'+'/'+htmlFile).toString());
```

Comment: Put the `fs.readFileSync` in the `finish` callback, not outside of it.

Comment: The console.log() will run first, before the file exists, since it's not part of the onfinished callback. So replace `console.log( 'done' );` with the readFile() call.

Comment: Not only that, but I think you have a typo in your code, you need an extra `)` before the `console.log(fs...`.

Comment: when i put read file inside on.finished return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'outPutPath\file.html'

Comment: Also, don't use the [`node-unzip` library](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip/issues/120)

Comment: what should i use, if you have a proposition write an answer :D

Comment: That GitHub issue links to this answer: [Simplest way to download and unzip files in Node.js cross-platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46967462/691711).  I would check against that.  I couldn't even get the `node-unzip` library to function.