# How to unzip file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression

I need to zip and unzip file with Node.js but I have a problem.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const zlib = require('zlib');



function UnZip(zip, paths) {

  var inp = fs.createReadStream("f:/test.zip");

  var Exzip = zlib.createUnzip();

  inp.pipe(Exzip).pipe("f:/");

}
```

Error:

> TypeError: dest.on is not a function

Comment: check this question, it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308110/simplest-way-to-download-and-unzip-files-in-node-js-cross-platform

Comment: which zlib library is that?

Comment: zlib does not zip the file, it converts into qzip format. So if you want zip format, you can use archiver library.

Comment: `.pipe("f:/")` is most likely the error: it needs to be a function (or a stream) instead you supplied a string.

Comment: tnx bro So how write .pipe("f:\"); ????

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you can do it with zlib module.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const fileContents = fs.createReadStream('file1.txt.gz');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('file1.txt');
const unzip = zlib.createGunzip();

fileContents.pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Zipping the file

```
const archiver = require('archiver'),
    archive  = archiver('zip'),
      fs       = require('fs'),
    output = fs.createWriteStream( 'mocks.zip');

archive.pipe(output);

// temp.txt file must be available in your folder where you 
// are writting the code or you can give the whole path

const file_buffer = fs.readFileSync('temp.txt')


archive.append(file_buffer, { name: 'tttt.txt'});


archive.finalize().then((err, bytes) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(err + bytes + ' total bytes');
});
```

unzipping a file

```
const unzip = require('unzip'),
      fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('temp1.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'path' }))
```

Comment: tnx bro ... But me need to UnCompress .zip File

Comment: bro please only use this =>  const zlib = require('zlib');

Comment: zlib library does not support zip format, you can gzip using zlib