# How would I unzip a zip file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to unzip a .zip file in node without any external libraries. How would i go about doing this?

I have tried using zlib but it returns incorrect header type

```
let zipfile = fs.readFileSync(fileinfomation.savelocation)   
zlib.gunzipSync(zipfile)
```

Edit
I have also tried using

```
let zipfile = fs.readFileSync(fileinfomation.savelocation)   
zlib.unzipSync(zipfile)
```

And it returned i caused the following error
Uncaught Error Error: incorrect header check

Link to zip https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-x64-archive

Comment: Thanks i edited my post, it is now returning an error "Incorrect header check"?
All i did was change gunzipsync to unzipsync

Comment: @jfriend00 please don't harass close voters in the comments

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308110/simplest-way-to-download-and-unzip-files-in-node-js-cross-platform) related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zlib does not appear to support decompressing a whole zip file archive (that contains multiple files) which is what your visual studio zip file is.

You will either have to use a different library that does support decompressing zip archive files (there are many different libraries on NPM that support that) or you can use child_process to run a zip decompressor that is already on your system.

If this is windows, you can run (using child_process) the built in `tar.exe` that can decompress zip archive files or you can get your own command-line decompressor (I use 7-zip myself) and run it as a child_process.