# How to download zip and directly extract zip via node?

Tags: node.js, zip, zlib

I was wondering if it is possible to use https.get() from the Node standard library to download a zip and directly extract it into a subfolder.

I have found many solutions that download the zip first and extract it afterwards. But is there a way to do it directly?

This was my attempt:

```js
const zlib = require("node:zlib");
const fs = require("fs");
const { pipeline } = require("node:stream");
const https = require("https");

const DOWNLOAD_URL =
  "https://downloadserver.com/data.zip";
const unzip = zlib.createUnzip();
const output = fs.createWriteStream("folderToExtract");

https.get(DOWNLOAD_URL, (res) => {
  pipeline(res, unzip, output, (error) => {
    if (error) console.log(error);
  });
});
```

But I get this error:

> Error: incorrect header check
> at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17) {
> errno: -3,
> code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
> }

I am curious, is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most unzippers start at the *end* of the zip file, reading the central directory there and using that to find the entries to unzip. This requires having the entire zip file accessible at the start.

What you'd need is a streaming unzipper, which starts at the beginning of the zip file. You can try [unzip-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip-stream) and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar to [Simplest way to download and unzip files in Node.js cross-platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308110/simplest-way-to-download-and-unzip-files-in-node-js-cross-platform)

An answer in the above discussion using same package:
[image]

You're getting the error probably because `zlib` only support `gzip` files and not `zip`

Comment: Downvote is because code snippets should not be images.